# Using Spring MongoTemplate to update nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Can anyone help with a MongoTemplate question?
I have got a record structure which has nested arrays and I want to update a specific entry in a 2nd level array.  I can find the appropriate entry easier enough by the Set path needs the indexes of both array entries & the '$' only refers to the leaf item.  For example if I had an array of teams which contained an array of player I need to generate an update path like :

```
val query = Query(Criteria.where( "teams.players.playerId").`is`(playerId))
val update = Update()
with(update) {
    set("teams.$.players.$.name", player.name)
```

This fails as the '$' can only be used once to refer to the index in the players array, I need a way to generate the equivalent '$' for the index in the teams array.

I am thinking that I need to use a separate Aggregate query using the something like this but I can't get it to work.

```
project().and(ArrayOperators.arrayOf( "markets").indexOf("")).`as`("index")
```

Any ideas for this Mongo newbie?

Comment: What is your mongo server version ? Run db.version() on shell to output the server version.

Comment: I'm on Mongo 3.6

Answer (score 0):

For others who is facing similar issue, One option is to use arrayFilters in UpdateOptions. But looks like mongotemplate in spring does not yet support the use of UpdateOptions directly. Hence, what can be done is:
`Sample for document which contain object with arrays of arrayObj (which contain another arrays of arrayObj).`

```
Bson filter = eq("arrayObj.arrayObj.id", "12345");
UpdateResult result = mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection(collectionName)
            .updateOne(filter,
                    new Document("$set", new Document("arrayObj.$[].arrayObj.$[x].someField"), "someValueToUpdate"),
                    new UpdateOptions().arrayFilters(
                            Arrays.asList(Filters.eq("x.id, "12345))
                    ));
```